# Adjusting Width for Responsive Web Design in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a Flutter application with a responsive design that needs to work across both web and mobile platforms. I've encountered an issue where the width of my web app's show menu widget does not match the width used in the mobile app. My goal is to adjust the web app's show menu width to be consistent with the mobile app's design.

Here's the code snippet that I'm working with:

```
responsive.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ResponsiveWeb extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  const ResponsiveWeb({super.key, required this.child});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints:  BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 600,),
              child: child,

      ),
    );
    
  }
}
```

```
appbar.dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ResponsiveWeb(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 202, 55),
              title: ResponsiveWeb(
                child: Row(
                  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          const Icon(
                            FontAwesomeIcons.checkDouble,
                            size: 24,
                            color: const Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                          ),
                      
                    Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          Tooltip(
                            message: 'Settings',
                            child: Semantics(
                              label: 'Pomodoro timer settings',
                              enabled: true,
                              readOnly: true,
                              child: IconButton(
                                icon: const Icon(
                                  Icons.settings_outlined,
                                  color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                                  size: 24,
                                  semanticLabel: 'Pomodoro timer Settings',
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) =>
                                            SettingsUIPomodoro()),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Tooltip(
                            message: 'Profile',
                            child: Semantics(
                              label: 'Pomodoro timer Profile',
                              enabled: true,
                              readOnly: true,
                              child: IconButton(
                                icon: const Icon(
                                  Icons.account_circle_outlined,
                                  color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                                  size: 24,
                                  semanticLabel: 'Pomodoro timer Profile',
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => Profile()),
                                  );
                                },
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
          
           
              ),
              actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              showMenu(
                  context: context,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  position: const RelativeRect.fromLTRB(1, 80, 0, 0),
                  items: [
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      child: ResponsiveWeb(
                        child: ListTile(
                          title: Text(
                            'Analytics',
                            style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                              color: const Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            ),
                          ),
                          trailing: Icon(
                            Icons.show_chart_outlined,
                            color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                            size: 20,
                            semanticLabel: 'Pomodoro timer Analytics',
                          ),
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) => Text('Analytics')),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    PopupMenuItem(
                      child: ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                          'Daily goals',
                          style: GoogleFonts.nunito(
                            color: const Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          ),
                        ),
                        trailing: Icon(
                          Icons.military_tech_outlined,
                          color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                          size: 20,
                          semanticLabel: 'Pomodoro timer Daily goals',
                        ),
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => Text('Daily goals')),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]);
            },
            icon: Tooltip(
              message: 'More',
              child: Semantics(
                label: 'Pomodoro timer More',
                enabled: true,
                readOnly: true,
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.more_vert_outlined,
                  color: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                  size: 24,
                  semanticLabel: 'Pomodoro timer More',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
```

I attempted to wrap the show menu widget with the `ResponsiveWeb` widget, aiming to control its maximum width, but this approach led to an error (please specify the error if possible). How can I effectively adjust the width of the show menu widget for the web app to align with the mobile app's design?

Comment: should i put appBar directly as child of responsive web?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GestureDetector` to get global position, and then use it on `showMenu`'s position. create a variable on top(inside build for statelesswidget but for stateful on state class). and then

```dart
GestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
  onTapDown: (details) {
    tapOffset = details.globalPosition;
    print(tapOffset);
  },
  child: IconButton(
    onPressed: () {
      showMenu(
          position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(
            tapOffset!.dx - 150, // assuming popUp width, can be controll by bottom `constraints` providing same width on min and max
            64,
            tapOffset?.dx ?? 0,
            0,
          ),
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxWidth: 600,
          ),
          context: context,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
```

A better solution will be calculating renderBox size.

Comment: Can you show me an example from the `tapOffset` variable, please? (How can I define it?)

Comment: put it under build method like `@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Offset? tapOffset;`

Comment: make sure to assign it, while i am using `!` on use case

Answer (score 1):

In responsive.dart you set the `maxWidth` property to max 600. That is why the is showing not full screen. Hope that helps.